# Decoding a file resource for scanning in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Stack Overflow, but I have a question about writing some Java code for an Android program.

I'm building a game for the Android phone, and when we are building levels we are aiming to scan them from text files that are stored in the res/raw for our project. My problem is that I can't figure out how to decode the resource in such a way that it can be interpreted by the Scanner. Right now my line of code just looks like:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File((R.raw.level1));
```

This is pretty much just a reinterpretation of the equivalent Java code, which would take a string with the level name. I'm guessing that I'm supposed to be using something like decodeResource for BitmapFactory, but I'm not sure where to look! Perhaps I shouldn't be approaching it as a File at all?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Activity:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(MyActivity.this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.level1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Looks like it will require some more editing of my code than I initially expected, or I might be doing it in the wrong class altogether.

Comment: @Anna, You should accept the former answer to thank @Herrrmann